# Can't change column name after creating a dataframe after group_by

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Probably a naive question, but I am not able to understand the same :

I did a groupby on one column in the dataframe :

```
df5 = df4.groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'].count()
```

when I print df5, I get :

```
Date_1
01/09/2019    20
02/09/2019    18
03/09/2019    44
04/09/2019    30
05/09/2019    34
06/09/2019    38
Name: Date_1, dtype: int64
```

Now, I want to change the column name of df5 to ['Date_1', 'count']

I tried :

```
df5.columns = ['Flight_Date', 'Count']
```

But this is not working, there is no error but it is not changing the column names.

Can anyone explain the reason for the same.

Thanks

Comment: @jezrael I am getting error, `ValueError: cannot insert Date_1, already exists`

Comment: Ok, use `df5 = df4.groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'].count().reset_index(name='Count')`

Comment: @jezrael This works, However could you explain me why this happens, want to know for learning.

Comment: Sure, if use `df4.groupby('Date_1')['Date_1'].count()` it return `Series` and for `DataFrame` is necessary convert index to column, error means Series name is same like index name and for prevent new columns both called `Date_1` is returned error. Solution is use `name` paramter for renaming index name